# Capital Greek \mathtt not showing in arxiv

Tags: math-mode, fonts, arxiv

I need to write something like `\mathtt{\Pi}`,
which renders nicely on my mac but both on arxiv and on coworkers' laptops does not work.

How can i typeset `\mathtt{\Pi}` in any latex document?

Bonus question: Why does this work on mac and not anywhere else?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

$\Pi\mathtt{\Pi}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Provide MWE for your issue.

Comment: the standard math tt font has a capital pi, presumably you are using a non standard font setup in the machines where it does not work. (Mac or not Mac will make no difference)

Comment: I added a test file to your question, please post the log from your co-worker's machine if that does not show two \Pi.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, i was about to upload the same MWE

concerning the logs, it's not an error, it juse does not show. 
I'm afraid i don't have access to those machines -- but the arxiv log is here:
https://pastebin.com/C4DcBWK1

Comment: looking at the log I reproduced the problem, do you see the same? (It would be very unlikely that the behaviour you describe is sysetm dependent)

Comment: the log shows `Missing character: There is no ^^E in font LinLibertineMT-tlf-t1!` (which strangely isn't in the arxiv log you pasted)

Comment: Neither the T1 nor the OT1 encoded Libertine Mono font has a capital Pi. I get no symbol from `\mathtt{\Pi}` with any version of TeX Live (MacTeX) I have, *unless* I remove `\usepackage{newtxmath}`; it should be `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`, actually, but adding the option doesn't make a difference with `\mathtt{\Pi}`.

Answer (score 3):

There are three different issues you need to solve for this to work.

First, legacy 7-bit font encodings from the late 1970s.  The `newtxmath` package (which you should be using with the `libertine` option if `libertine` is your text font) sets the `\mathtt` alphabet to the 7-bit OML encoding.  This would be fine, as it is the only legacy encoding that contains uppercase and lowercase Latin and Greek letters—except that there is no OML-encoded font file for Libertine Mono.  (It would theoretically be possible to create one with FontForge, but you need this to work with arXiv.)  In fact, to the best of my knowledge, there is none for any upright monospaced font.

You can fix this by loading `\usepackage{libertinust1math}` as a replacement for `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`.  This will leave `\Pi` using the default OT1 encoding, rather than OML, which might cause problems elsewhere, but will at least let you use OT1 fonts in math mode.  Unfortunately, it will redefine `\mathtt` as Computer Modern Typewriter.

You can work around that problem by calling `\SetMathAlphabet` again, to change `\mathtt` to [a different legacy monospaced font.](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-mono)

The only other encodings containing Π are OML, the 8-bit LGR encoding (which requires some other packages and has even fewer fonts available) and the 7-bit OT1 encoding.  The latter is what you need to use.  However, neither Linux Libertine Mono nor Libertinus Mono has this glyph in its OT1 font file.

Therefore, the solution has three steps: load `libertinust1math` as your Libertine-compatible math font, load a different legacy typewriter font, and call `\SetMathAlphabet` to redefine `\mathtt` as the OT1 encoding of that font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sb]{libertinus-type1}
\usepackage[type1, semibold]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{normal}{OT1}{SourceCodePro-TLF}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\Pi\mathtt{\Pi}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

If that definition of `\mathtt` breaks something else in your document, you can as an alternative declare a new math symbol `\mttPi`, from slot `"05` of font `{OT1}{SourceCodePro-TLF}{m}{n}`, or the font of your choice.

In the unlikely event that you need a bold typewriter math alphabet, you can also declare `\setmathfont` for math version `bold` as well as `normal`, with semibold or bold weight instead of `m`.

One final note: If you’re not forced to use PDFLaTeX by the limitations of ArXiv, I’d normally recommend switching to the modern toolchain and `unicode-math`.  This is the rare time where that doesn’t solve a font-encoding issue right out of the box.  There is no Greek `\mathtt` alphabet defined in Unicode 10.  Instead, you need to work around this by loading a different typerwriter font as a math typeface, which you can do with `\setmathfontface`, and then declaring a symbol like `\mttPi`.

Comment: wow!
now, what if i actually did not want libertine?
i mean, it was added to the MWE from someone else, not by me ...

Comment: @Squera Huh, David Carlisle added that in, and I’m not sure why. Must’ve had a reason. Okay, if you prefer Computer-Modern-stye fonts, you would still need to use the OT1 encoding, but you could use the `cmtt` font family, or Latin Modern.

Comment: @Squera In the middle of something else right now, but just replacing `SourceCodePro-TLF` with `cmtt` or `lmtt` ought to work. Might edit later.

Comment: @Squera Simpler, though, to load `zlmtt`.